# Did Mad Eye Moody see Scorpius, Albus, and Delphi inside the Maze during the Third Task?

Tags: harry-potter, the-cursed-child

Scorpius, Albus, and Delphi go to the Triwizard Maze in *Harry Potter and the Cursed Child*. Mad Eye Moody  (Barty Crouch Junior) was patrolling outside the maze. His magical eye could see through the hedges.

Didn't he notice two boys and a young woman there?  He might have done so because Cedric interacts with them and we know Moody had his eye on Cedric.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Triwizard games are historically host to a range of foul play, so the actions of the Cursed Child trio don't raise suspicions that something especially out of the normal is going on.

Even if "Moody" had noticed them, it is advantageous to him to let their antics play out, as "Moody" is Barty Crouch Jr, and has the secret agenda of getting Harry to the cup in the last round. Add to this, he is undercover, posing as Alastor Moody, and so cannot do anything too rash. At most, he would have monitored them until realising it wasn't Harry they were sabotaging. Neither "Moody" or the eye are shown to have Legimency capabilities, so all "Moody" would see is three Durmstrang students sabotaging Cedric

Comment: Please read the play. The trio did go back to the final task.

Comment: Indeed Gariman Singh